# Construct an Adjacency List from a List of edges?

Tags: python-2.7, graph, graph-algorithm

In context of graph algorithms, we are usually given a convenient representation of a graph (usually as an adjacency list or an adjacency matrix) to operate on.

My question is, what is an efficient way to **construct** an Adjacency list from a given **list of all edges**?

*For the purpose of the question, assume that edges are a list of tuples (as in python) and (a,b) denotes a **directed** edge from a to b.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A combination of `itertools.groupby` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)), sorting and `dict` comprehension could get you started:

```
from itertools import groupby

edges = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3)]

adj = {k: [v[1] for v in g] for k, g in groupby(sorted(edges), lambda e: e[0])}
# adj: {1: [2, 3], 2: [3]}
```

This sorts and groups the edges by their source node, and stores a `list` of target nodes for each source node. Now you can access all adjacent nodes of `1` via `adj[1]`