# Convert community structure (list) to adjacency list

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Given community structure(a list of lists):

`[[A,B,C], [B,D,E,G], [A,C,F,H],[F,K, H]]`

and supposed each edge has weight 1, undirected within subgroup.

I would like to find the most influential person, who has shortest connection with G, F (minimum sum of edge) by applying Breadth/ Depth First Search for each person.

Here is the generic code of Breadth First Search:

```
def bfs_paths(graph, start, goal):
    queue = [(start, [start])]
    while queue:
        (vertex, path) = queue.pop(0)
        for next in graph[vertex] - set(path):
            if next == goal:
                yield path + [next]
            else:
                queue.append((next, path + [next]))
```

The thing is 'graph' should be represented as adjacency list. For example:

```
graph = {'A': set(['B', 'C', 'F', 'H']),
         'B': set(['D', 'E','G']),
         'C': set(['A', 'F', 'H']),
         'D': set(['B', 'E', 'G' ]),
         'E': set(['B', 'D', 'G' ]),
         'F': set(['K', 'H']),
         'G': set(['B', 'D', 'E'])
         'H': set(['K', 'F']}
```

Main question: How do you convert community structure (list) to adjacency list?

Side-question: Is there any other algorithm suitable?

Edit1: I have tried follow this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524816/construct-an-adjacency-list-from-a-list-of-edges). But I stuck at improving the code to meet the expected result

Comment: Did you try anything to convert it? Can you share that code

Comment: I am not clear on what is `community structure`. It looks like your are talking about clustered nodes. In that case centroids have to be known. If it not the case, can you give some external link with definition of what community means?

Comment: If the graph is undirected why isn't `F` and `H` in `A`'s agency list?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: I did try following [this ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524816/construct-an-adjacency-list-from-a-list-of-edges)

Comment: @spiralarchitect: maybe [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure)

Comment: @MarkMeyer: I forgot them, will update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all the communities are completely connected, you can convert to an adjacency list fairly quickly by iterating over the groups and using `setdefault` to make a new entry where needed and adding the nodes:

```
community = [['A','B','C'], ['B','D','E','G'], ['A','C','F','H'],['F','K','H']]

adj_list = {}

for group in community:
    for member in group:
        adj_list.setdefault(member, set()).update((set(group) - {member}))
```

`adj_list` will then be:

```
{'A': {'B', 'C', 'F', 'H'},
 'B': {'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G'},
 'C': {'A', 'B', 'F', 'H'},
 'D': {'B', 'E', 'G'},
 'E': {'B', 'D', 'G'},
 'G': {'B', 'D', 'E'},
 'F': {'A', 'C', 'H', 'K'},
 'H': {'A', 'C', 'F', 'K'},
 'K': {'F', 'H'}}
```

An alternative would be to use a `defaultdict(set)` then you can just index into it and update in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe that the solution is so simple with ```setdefault```

Answer (score 2):

This may get the desired result

```
A1=[['A','B','C'], ['B','D','E','G'], ['A','C','F','H'],['F','K', 'H']]
dict1={}
for l in A1:
    for i in l:
        dict1[i]=[]

for i in dict1:

        index=100
        for j in A1:
            try:

                if j.index(i)<index:
                    index=j.index(i)
                    dict1[i]=[]
                    for k in j:
                        if k!=i:
                            dict1[i].append(k)
            except:
                pass
```